# Echos from Post-Build events are only shown after build is complete

Tags: visual-studio, echo, post-build-event

I am using Visual Studio 2017, but the same behavior was found in Visual Studio 2015.

I have several steps in my post-build events and echo messages in between, like so

```
echo Copying assets...
xCopy "$(TargetDir)..\..\11 Assets" "$(TargetDir)" /i /s /e /y /q
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug goto :exit
echo Copying compiled files to release folder...
mkdir "$(TargetDir)_ForRelease"
xCopy "$(TargetDir)App.exe" "$(TargetDir)_ForRelease" /y /q

[...]
```

Now this all works fine, but what I wanted was to see the `echo` messages appear one by one in the build output window while the post-build is running (so I know at what step in the post-build I am).
Instead, no messages are displayed during the post-build and instead all messages are displayed as one chunk after the build is completed.

I found [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800587/visual-studio-2010-output-panel-not-updating-postbuild-output), but it talks about the output window locking up completely, which is not the case here. Everything is responsive, the messages are just not displayed immediately.

Is there a way to solve this and display the messages immediately during the post-build, or is this just how the build process works?

Comment: VS2019 does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using MSBuild directly as an external tool from the toolbar. I basically made a "Build Project" button that calls MSBuild.exe on the solution.

MSBuild shows a command window that prints out the post build steps in real time.